# Converting MMDDYYYY to 01-JAN-YY

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime

I have a string in the format in = "01012012". I want it to convert to: 01-JAN-12. How do I achieve it in C#?

Comment: What's `02012012`, Jan-2 or Feb-1? (i.e. do you use the European or the US format?)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The format's in the title. Month first, followed by day.

Comment: the headline says: month-day-year so this should be feb-1. take a look at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("01012012", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newDateString = dateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

EDIT: Changed output to 2 digit date (instead of 4)

Comment: datetime.ParseExact takes min of 3 arguments.

Comment: Correcto, it also accepts a System.IFormatProvider which I believe you can provide like this: DateTime.ParseExact("01012012", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); - Obviously depends on your use case

Answer (score 0):

**Got my answer:**

```
     CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("08312012", "MMddyyyy", provider);
     string getDate = date.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

Thanks guys!!!

Comment: Looks like your answer is exactly the same as Adam's. You should accept his answer instead of posting your own.